# Images Stuck on Server

Tags: ftp, webserver, sql-server, web

I've run into a strange problem with images being "stuck" on the server.

The problem began when I uploaded an updated picture via FTP (I use Cyberduck for Mac) to override the picture. This didn't work, the picture wasn't overridden at all. So, I tried deleting the picture from the server, but it wasn't removed. I cleared the cache, tried different browsers, but the image at the given absolute URL just never disappeared. But, using 2 different FTP clients, the image is shown to not be there. I used the file manager provided with cpanel as well, which also showed the directory empty.

I then experimented and deleted the entire folder of pictures with FTP, but the entire set of pictures was still accessible online, but shown as empty.

I'm confused how there can be an absolute URL of pictures that works, even when FTP shows it as empty.

For example, from my index.html file, the path to pictures is img/team, which is full of 10 portraits of team members. I deleted all of the 10 jpg pictures, and even the entire team folder.

http://myurl.com/img/team when loaded in browser doesn't load, 404 not found http://myrul.com/img/team/person.jpg does load, this is picture "stuck on server"

How can an individual file be accessible, when the folder containing that file isn't? Is there a way to investigate files on server that FTP clients can't "see" for some reason?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hint: The web server root folder isn't the ftp root folder.

Comment: Thank you for that hint.  I'm looking at what I think is the root folder of the server.  Folders are "etc", "logs", "mail", "public_ftp", "public_html", "ssl", "tmp",  and "www".  To be honest I don't have much experience with the other folders, I've only worked with public_html and www folder (I also don't understand what the difference is between those)

Could you please elaborate on what I should be looking for?  I'm looking through all these folders in server root, and I don't know exactly what to do.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting via FTP, you're accessing the `public_ftp` folder.

When viewing over HTTP (in the web browser), you're reading from the `public_html` folder.

NOTE: The `public_html` and `www` often point to the same folder with a symlink.

Comment: Thank you for that answer.  So, when you're viewing the public_html directory through FTP, is it **not** the same directory as accessing through HTTP?  Because when I view public_html I still can't find the "hidden" images that I can only see using HTTP.  The public_ftp folder only includes an empty "incoming" folder.

Comment: What is in the `www` folder?  Also, upload a file via FTP and see where it goes.

Comment: The `www` folder has exactly the same contents at the `public_html` folder for me.  I'm confused by what you mean when you say "see where it goes".  When uploading via FTP, I choose public_html (www would be same) and upload into whatever directory, and the file is sent no problem.  The issue here is I still can't "view" certain files, and I'm not sure if it's an issue of FTP to not be able to see them.  Here is the example below of exactly what is confusing me:

[http://peterkrieg.com/checkmate/img/team](http://peterkrieg.com/checkmate/img/team)

Comment: [http://peterkrieg.com/checkmate/img/team/powell.jpg](http://peterkrieg.com/checkmate/img/team/powell.jpg)

The jpg loads fine in browser, even though I deleted the team folder through FTP.  the team folder gives 404 error when I try to load in browser.